# Regular Expression in ASP.NET for decimal validation

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am currently attempting to use a regular expression validator control in ASP.NET to validate a textbox that will be used for input for a database that accepts a decimal value.

I want this value to accept up to 18 digits before the decimal, and 1 digit after. With the decimal point and the digit after it being optional

For example all the following would be accepted

- 1.0
- 100.1
- 123456789123456789.2
- 123456789123456789

But these examples would not

- 1.01
- 1234567891234567891
- 1234567891234567891.0

I am currently using this as my regular expression, however it seems to be accepting things that are more than 18 digits before the decimal point.

```
^(\d{1,18})+(\.\d{1})?$
```

Anyone know what I did wrong here?

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: Remove the `+` quantifier. It's allowing `at least one` group of 1 - 18 digits

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I am just starting out with regular expressions, and this is one heck of a complex topic. Seriously can't express my gratitude enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the '+'

`^(\d{1,18})(.\d{1})?$`